# Grunt Filerev JS inject into HTML

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have the following structure (I'm using Django).

```
app
|__ templates
  |__ index.html
|__ static
  |__ js
    |__ main.js
```

What I need to do is:

1. Uglify/minify `main.js` into `main.min.js`
2. File rev `main.min.js` into something like `main.min.12345678.js`
3. Make sure `index.html` has the new `main.min.12345678.js` file

My `index.html` looks like:

```
// ....
<script src="{% static "js/main.js" %}"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying out Grunt filerev (https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) and I am able to run that properly, but how do I replace that `main.js` with the versioned `main.js`??

I tried using grunt usemin, however is there a way where I DON'T have to create a new `index.html` file?

Comment: When you say "replace that `main.js` with the versioned `main.js`" do you mean "replace that `main.min.js` with the versioned `main.min.js`"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [grunt-filerev-replace](https://github.com/solidusjs/grunt-filerev-replace)?

I am using it for the exact same reason successfully.